# ¿Cómo hago para calcular cuánto recaudó cada municipio con vectores python?

Tags: python

Quiero calcular el recaudo de cada municipio en base a mi línea de código que ya calcula una determinada factura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen se ve que ya se calculó todo, solo quiero que abajo se muestre cuánto recaudó cada municipio, es decir: si hay dos usuarios del mismo municipio se sumen sus facturas y las muestre; deben ser solo 5 municipios, no es necesario que se le pregunte con un input de qué municipio es. Intenté crear un vector municipio y que preguntara a qué municipio pertenece, pero no pude encontrar la manera de colocar cuánto recaudó cada municipio. La manera en la que se debe hacer es ya asignar 5 municipios al vector municipio y así hacerlo ya que solo piden 5 municipios, pero no he podido hacerlo.
Acá les dejo el código:

````
import random
codigo=[]
usuario=[]
estrato=[]
consumo=[]
factura=[]
municipio=[]
mun =str("")
c1=0;c2=0;c3=0;c4=0;c5=0;c6=0
con1=0;con2=0;con3=0;con4=0;con5=0;con6=0
n=int(input(" --Ingrese cantidad de usuarios-- "))
for i in range(n):
  cod=random.randint(100,999)
  usu=input(" --Ingrese nombre de usuario-- ")
  mun=input(" --Ingrese su municipio-- ")
  est=random.randint(1,6)
  con=random.randint(45,121)
  codigo.append(cod)
  usuario.append(usu)
  estrato.append(est)
  consumo.append(con)
  municipio.append(mun)
  if est==1:
    c1=+1
    con1=con1+con
    factura.append(con*700)
  if est==2:
    c2=+1
    con2=con2+con
    factura.append(con*840)
  if est==3:
    c3=+1
    con3=con3+con
    factura.append(con*1100)
  if est==4:
    c4=+1
    con4=con4+con
    factura.append(con*1350)
  if est==5:
    c5=+1
    con5=con5+con
    factura.append(con*1800)
  if est==6:
    c6=+1
    con6=con6+con
    factura.append(con*2120)

print("CODIGO\tUSUARIO\tMUNICIPIO\tESTRATO\tCONSUMO\tFACTURA")
for i in range (n):
    print(codigo[i],"\t",usuario[i],"\t",municipio[i],"\t",estrato[i],"\t",consumo[i],"\t",factura[i])

print("")
print("Estadisticas")
print(" ")##
##Recaudo de cada municipio
print("Recaudo de cada municipio")
print(municipio[i])
print()
print(" ")
#Recaudo de cada estrato
print("Recaudo de cada estrato")
print("reca1\treca2\treca3\treca4\treca5\treca6")
print(con1*700,"\t",con2*840,"\t",con3*1100,"\t",con4*1350,"\t",con5*1800,"\t",con6*2120)
print("")##
#porcentajes de cada estrato
porc1=(con1*100)/n
porc2=(con2*100)/n
porc3=(con3*100)/n
porc4=(con4*100)/n
porc5=(con5*100)/n
porc6=(con6*100)/n
print("Porcentaje de cada estrato")
print("porc1\tporc2\tporc2\tporc3\tporc4\tporc5\tporc6")
print(porc1,"\t",porc2,"\t",porc3,"\t",porc4,"\t",porc5,"\t",porc6)
print(" ")##
#Porcentaje de usuarios en estrato 1 o 2 (por aparte)
print("el % de usuario de estrato 1 es: " , c1*100/n)
print("el % de usuario de estrato 2 es: " , c2*100/n)
print(" ")##
#Factura más alta y de que usuario es y Factura más baja y de que usuario es
print(" la factura mas alta es: ",max(factura),"y le pertenece a: ",usuario[factura.index(max(factura))]) #max es para hayar el valor mayor en la lista que se especifique entre corchetes() y el index es para tomar el valor mayor de factura
print(" la factura mas baja es: ",min(factura),"y le pertenece a: ",usuario[factura.index(min(factura))])
print(" ")##
#Promedio de consumo de kilovatios del estrato 2
print( " el promedio de consumo es: " ,con2/c2 )
factura.sort() # sort es para ordenar los elementos de menor a mayor en la lista factura
print(factura)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Dado que lo tienes en arreglos diferentes pero con la misma cantidad, puedes simplemente mapearlos a un `dict` e ir sumando la cantidad

Inicializamos un diccionario vacío

```
##Recaudo de cada municipio
print("Recaudo de cada municipio")  
map_municipio = {}
```

Después iteramos en cada municipio y obtenemos su factura, agregamos el nombre del municipio como `key` y sumamos el valor si ya existe un valor previo o lo inicializamos como 0.

```
for i  in range(n):
    map_municipio[municipio[i]] = map_municipio.get(municipio[i], 0) + factura[i]
```

Después imprimimos el diccionario

```
for municipio_tmp, factura_tmp in map_municipio.items():
    print(municipio_tmp, "\t", factura_tmp)
```

Parte de ese código completo.

```
##Recaudo de cada municipio
print("Recaudo de cada municipio")  
map_municipio = {}
for i  in range(n):
    map_municipio[municipio[i]] = map_municipio.get(municipio[i], 0) + factura[i]
for municipio_tmp, factura_tmp in map_municipio.items():
    print(municipio_tmp, "\t", factura_tmp)
```